# write xml with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this may be a truly stupid question but I haven't readily found the answer.
once i modify the xml tree as necessary, how do I write it back out to file?

code:

```
workbook = open("C:\\Users\\rabdel.WINCMPT\\Documents\\Retail Footwear.twb")
soup = BeautifulSoup(workbook)

for dashboard in soup.findAll("dashboard"):
    print dashboard["name"]
    if dashboard["name"] == "S1":
        dashboard.extract()

for window in soup.findAll("window"):
    print "class:",window["class"]
    if "name" in [x[0] for x in window.attrs]:
        print "name:",window["name"]
        if window["name"] == "S1":
            window.extract()
```

Comment: Have you tried writing str(soup) to a file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simplest way, get the output as a string and write to file:

```
f = open(workbook.name, "w")
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()
```

Comment: or, in several cases may be better
f.write(str(soup))

Comment: @AlexLelekov, indeed, Graphpad Prism pzfx works with `str()` but not `.prettify()` output

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: [you can turn a Beautiful Soup document (or any subset of it) into a string with the `str` function, or the `prettify` or `renderContents` methods. You can also use the `unicode` function to get the whole document as a Unicode string.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Printing%20a%20Document)

Then just write that string to a file as you would any other string.